# CoreData concurrency violation on fetch request dispatched to the appropriate managed context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I've got CoreData concurrency violation assertions enabled in my project, which have been great for tracking down and fixing errors in our usage of it. However, I occasionally get issues on fetch requests where I can't determine what we're doing wrong.

All of our managed contexts are private queue concurrency types other than one that is a main queue concurrency type. This is a block of code that occasionally triggers the concurrency violation:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchFromCacheEntitiesWithClass:(Class)entityClass
                               predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
                         sortDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
                          managedContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedContext
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[entityClass entityName]];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    request.fetchBatchSize = 30;
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    [managedContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        results = [managedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSAssert(!error, @"fetch had an error, investigate why");
    }];
    return results;
}
```

The entityName method exists on all of our CoreData classes, is generated from MOGenerator, and I've double checked that it's correct for all of our classes. The violation in this snippet happens on the executeFetchRequest call.

One thing to note is that we've only seen this occur in the simulator, never on a device. It has me leaning towards a simulator bug, though I don't normally like to assign blame to tools since developer error is so much more common.

Comment: Is it possible any of the NSPredicate instances passed in have references to NSManagedObject instances from another managed context? It's hard to see anything else that might be going wrong, and like you say, it'd make me nervous writing it off as a simulator defect. I have seen false positive concurrency violations from Xcode, but never as an intermittent thing like this -- some versions of Xcode (e.g. 7.0 if I remember right) threw them all the time, making the flag useless.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Most of the time the predicate parameter is actually nil. Basically every time it's used, it's just matching one string property using a passed in string reference. I don't actually think there's a way to have the predicate trigger the error, since even if we did something like [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyName = %@", managedObject.propertyName], it should trigger the assertion on instantiating the predicate, right?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. What version of Xcode are you using? Does it matter what version of iOS the simulator has?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.2, and iOS simulator version 9.2. Two of my coworkers are using Xcode 7.3 and iOS simulator 9.3. We haven't done any extensive testing on different versions because I figured if we're at the point where some Xcode versions have it and others don't, it's almost definitely a tools bug at which point it becomes pretty low priority for us.